# while calling the seq2seq_model to get train and test prediction im getting this error?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, chatbot, seq2seq

> ```
> '''
> training_predictions, test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs, [-1]),
>                                                        targets,
>                                                        keep_prob,
>                                                        batch_size,
>                                                        sequence_length,
>                                                        len(answerword2int),
>                                                        len(questionword2int),
>                                                        encoding_embedding_size,
>                                                        decoding_embedding_size,
>                                                        rnn_size,
>                                                        num_layers,
>                                                        questionword2int)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<ipython-input-28-b2be08c330e7>", line 12, in <module>
>     questionword2int)
>
>   File "<ipython-input-22-c4f5411a2dc7>", line 26, in seq2seq_model
>     batch_size)
>
>   File "<ipython-input-21-472a41dad669>", line 34, in decoder_rnn
>     batch_size)
>
> TypeError: decode_test_set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'batch_size'
> '''
>
> '''
> Its the following code
> #decoding the test/validation set
> def decode_test_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embeddings_matrix, sos_id, eos_id, maximum_length, num_words,
> ```
>
> sequence_length, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob,
>   batch_size):
>           attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
>           attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function =
>   tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states,
>   attention_option= 'bahdanau', num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
>           test_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference(output_function, 
>                                                                                     encoder_state[0], 
>                                                                                     attention_keys, 
>                                                                                     attention_values, 
>                                                                                     attention_score_function, 
>                                                                                     attention_construct_function,
>                                                                                     decoder_embeddings_matrix, 
>                                                                                     sos_id, 
>                                                                                     eos_id, 
>                                                                                     maximum_length, 
>                                                                                     num_words,
>                                                                                     name= "attn_dec_inf")
>           test_prediction, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell, 
>                                                                          test_decoder_function, 
>                                                                          scope = decoding_scope)
>
> ```
>     return test_prediction
>
>
> #creating the decoder rnn
> def decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input, decoder_embeddings_matrix, encoder_state, num_words, sequence_length, rnn_size, num_layers,
> ```
>
> word2int, keep_prob, batch_size):
>           with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
>               lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
>               lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
>               decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
>               weights = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1)
>               biases = tf.zeros_initializer()
>               output_function = lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x,
>                                                                             num_words,
>                                                                             None,
>                                                                             scope = decoding_scope,
>                                                                             weights_initializer = weights,
>                                                                             biases_initializer = biases)
>
> ```
>         training_predictions = decode_training_set(encoder_state,
>                                                    decoder_cell,
>                                                    decoder_embedded_input,
>                                                    sequence_length,
>                                                    decoding_scope,
>                                                    output_function,
>                                                    keep_prob,
>                                                    batch_size)
>         decoding_scope.reuse_variables()
>         test_prediction = decode_test_set(encoder_state,
>                                           decoder_cell,
>                                           decoder_embeddings_matrix,
>                                           word2int['<SOS>'],
>                                           word2int['<EOS>'],
>                                           sequence_length - 1,
>                                           num_words,
>                                           decoding_scope,
>                                           output_function,
>                                           keep_prob,
>                                           batch_size)
>     return training_predictions, test_prediction
>
> #building the seq2seq model
>
> def seq2seq_model(inputs, targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, answers_num_words, questions_num_words,
> ```
>
> encoder_embedding_size, decoder_embedding_size, rnn_size, num_layers,
>   questionwords2int):
>           encoder_embedded_input = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(inputs,
>                                                                     answers_num_words + 1,
>                                                                     encoder_embedding_size,
>                                                                     initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1))
>           encoder_state = encoder_rnn(encoder_embedded_input,
>                                       rnn_size,
>                                       num_layers,
>                                       keep_prob,
>                                       sequence_length)
>           preprocessed_targets = preprocess_targets(targets,
>                                                     questionwords2int,
>                                                     batch_size)
>           decoder_embeddings_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([questions_num_words + 1,
>   decoder_embedding_size],0 ,1))
>           decoder_embedded_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings_matrix,
>                                                           preprocessed_targets)
>           training_predictions, test_predictions = decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input,
>                                                                decoder_embeddings_matrix,
>                                                                encoder_state,
>                                                                questions_num_words,
>                                                                sequence_length,
>                                                                rnn_size,
>                                                                num_layers,
>                                                                questionword2int,
>                                                                keep_prob,
>                                                                batch_size)
>
> ```
>     return training_predictions, test_predictions
>
>
> #training the seq2seq modal
> #setting up the hyperparameter
>
> epochs = 100
> batch_size = 64
> rnn_size = 512
> num_layers = 3
> encoding_embedding_size = 512
> decoding_embedding_size = 512
> learning_rate = 0.01
> learning_rate_decay = 0.9
> min_learning_rate = 0.0001
> keep_probability = 0.5
>
> #defining a session
>
> tf.reset_default_graph()
> session = tf.InteractiveSession()
>
> #loading the modal input
>
> inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob = modal_input()
>
> #setting the sequence length
>
> sequence_length = tf.placeholder_with_default(25, None, name = 'sequence_length')
>
> #getting the shape of input tensor
>
> input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
>
> #getting the training and test predivtions
> training_predictions, test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs, [-1]),
>                                                        targets,
>                                                        keep_prob,
>                                                        batch_size,
>                                                        sequence_length,
>                                                        len(answerword2int),
>                                                        len(questionword2int),
>                                                        encoding_embedding_size,
>                                                        decoding_embedding_size,
>                                                        rnn_size,
>                                                        num_layers,
>                                                        questionword2int)
> '''
> ```

Comment: Please try to edit and format the code a bit better.

Comment: Sorry for it, I'm new :)

Answer (score 1):

Please re-read your error SLOWLY this time. 
You would see your function `decode_test_set()` definition has 12 arguments defined. However, while calling it during prediction you are providing only 11 values to it and missing the last one which is `batch_size`.

Also, just for future questions, please format your question properly so that it is easy to read and the community can help you better.

Comment: Yeah, now it's working. Thank you
In the tutorial, they passed only 11.
Next time I'll keep care of formating, Sorry for that